# Best architecture to set a realtime logging window to write from different threads like output window in visualstudio

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, architecture

I am designing an application and it runs different components each on a different thread. I need a way to report back to the user interface the state of those components and the tasks they complete and if any errors occurred. My first approach was to write from all the different components to a log file. And then I monitored that file for changes, to reload the changes in a text box (my output window). However I noticed that using file monitor does not perform very well, and it slows downs the component threads and their tasks. So I was thinking to create something like the output windows in vs2010, where they can log any data while debugging, it seems to be very efficient, and can hold a lot of data. Any ideas what would be the best approach? One important fact, is that there should be a way to communicate all the component threads with the logging output window, to display results, avoid collisions, etc. I am using .NET 4.0

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just improve your idea with writing to the log file, just do it async, so you will not block the thread.

You can use something like [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

Comment: Have you tried this before? you think is the best approach? why does it need to be taken to a file, rather than just go into the textbox/datagrid? I forgot to mention some components work with the HD, so not sure if monitoring the logging will somehow slow things down. Another thing I was thinking was put everything to the log, but just load N lines. so it loads faster, not much disc activity, and the user can keep all the logs, but just view the latest in realtime.

Comment: 1. yes, I've tried async logging and it doesn't affect the performance.

 2. file (or another persistent place) is good in case you need to keep the logged data. Nlog and log4net supports different appenders so you can use a file or db etc.

Comment: seems you want to implement a functionality of a Unix command **tail**
for reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)

Comment: also this app could be useful if you are going to try log4net
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30795/C-WPF-Log4Net-Viewer

Comment: Looks about right, I am gonna try to improve the current algorithm, to see if I get it to make it more efficient and better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't see why you can't do something like in this example code (I must say that I consider that you are doing all the syncing and thread stopping, this is just a quick example of using Control.Invoke to make it thread safe, also you can use BeginInvoke and it won't block threads that are writing to the textBox):

```
        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        bool closeThreads;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            closeThreads = false;
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
                threads.Add(t);
                t.Start(i);
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            closeThreads = true;
            foreach (Thread t in threads)
            {
                if (t.ThreadState != ThreadState.Stopped)
                    t.Join(3);
            }
        }

        delegate void textWriter(string textToWrite);
        void WriteText(string textToWrite)
        {
            this.textBox1.AppendText(textToWrite);
        }

        void ThreadMethod(object i)
        {
            int threadNumber = (int)i;
            int currentNumber = 100 * threadNumber;
            Random rand = new Random(threadNumber);
            while(!closeThreads)
            {
                currentNumber = (currentNumber + rand.Next(0,100))%1000;
                Thread.Sleep(currentNumber);
                //textBox1.Invoke(new textWriter(WriteText), new object[]{"Thread " + threadNumber.ToString() + " " + currentNumber.ToString() + Environment.NewLine});
                //this won't block your threads
                string text = "Thread " + threadNumber.ToString() + " " + currentNumber.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            textBox1.BeginInvoke(new textWriter(WriteText), new object[]{text});
            }
        }
```

In order to try the code, you will need to make a form with two `Buttons` and one `TextBox`